# c++ multiplying two large numbers stored in linked list

Tags: c++, c++11, math, linked-list, integer-arithmetic

I am trying to write a code which will multiply two big numbers. Both numbers are divided and stored in a linked list.

In my case in every node there is 8 digit. for example: 324367823457572583 will be stored as

32 | 43678234 | 57572583.

Here is the code:

```
std::list<long long> multiply(const std::list<long long>& _a, const std::list<long long>& _b)
{
    std::list<long long> ret;
    int mod = 1e8, rem = 0;
    auto retit = ret.rbegin(), cur = retit;
    for(auto it2 = _b.rbegin(); it2 != _b.rend(); ++it2, ++cur)
    {
        retit = cur;

        for(auto it1 = _a.rbegin(); it1 != _a.rend(); ++it1, ++retit)
        {
            long long a = (*it2) * (*it1) + rem;
            if(retit == ret.rend())
                ret.push_front(a%mod);
            else
                a += *retit, *retit = a%mod;
            rem = a/mod;
        }
        *retit += rem, rem = 0;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I believe this code should work, but it outputs wrong answer...

34677523234 * 672891258627 =

2333420 22549932 95439718    (calculator output)

2328204 22549932 95439718    (my output)

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple problems in your multiplication routine.

- 32 bit overflow when multiplying two integers
- dereferencing `retit` that points to `rend()`

Here's [corrected version](https://ideone.com/3fz1Va):

```
std::list<int> multiply(const std::list<int>& _a, const std::list<int>& _b)
{
    std::list<int> ret;
    int mod = 100000000, rem = 0;
    auto retit = ret.rbegin(), cur = retit;
    for (auto it2 = _b.rbegin(); it2 != _b.rend(); ++it2, ++cur)
    {
        retit = cur;

        for (auto it1 = _a.rbegin(); it1 != _a.rend(); ++it1, ++retit)
        {
            long long a = static_cast<long long>(*it2) * (*it1) + rem;
            if (retit == ret.rend())
                ret.push_front(a%mod);
            else
                a += *retit, *retit = a%mod;
            rem = (int)(a / mod);
        }
        if (rem)
        {
            if (retit == ret.rend())
                ret.push_front(rem);
            else
                *retit += rem;
            rem = 0;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Output for your sample input:

```
2333420 22549932 95439718
```

Comment: (long long)value  is a c cast... you better should use the c++ casts (static_cast<long long>(value)). there are the following casts: dynamic_cast <new_type> (expression)
reinterpret_cast <new_type> (expression)
static_cast <new_type> (expression)
const_cast <new_type> (expression)

Comment: @Thomas no special reason, just a matter of preference.

Comment: if (rem)
        {
            if (retit == ret.rend())
                ret.push_front(rem);
            else
                *retit += rem;
            rem = 0;
        }
that one fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the line `long long a = (*it2) * (*it1) + rem;`

`*it1`, `*it2` are `int`s, so the result of the multiplication is also an `int`, which will overflow. You should cast to `long long` before the multiplication:

```
long long a = (long long)*it2 * *it1 + rem;
```

Comment: sorry for misleading.. actual code is very big so I edited function and seems like I made mistake. I will edit

Comment: the output that I wrote was for long long